# How to restrict Farm Account access for sharepoint 2010 site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have requirement How to restrict  Farm Account  access for sharepoint 2010  site collection?

Could you please provide steps to configure the same in my environment?

Many thanks,
Santhosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the Farm User by removing the permission of that user from the User Policy of Web Application.

Follow the below steps.

Central Administration ->Application Management->Manage web applications->choose the web application which contain the site collection->User Policy

Make sure the user has no permission on the web application.

Refer to [Remove permission from User Policy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4d7bf645-cb06-4f49-b467-a6d9f0d33ae1/remove-user-access-to-the-sharepoint-2010-site-collection?forum=sharepointadminprevious) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The SharePoint Farm Account should have access to the sharepoint content. Unless you restrict the user in web application user policy(it's not recommended), you cannot limit this account.